# Connect two autonomous networks (with their own ISP) via LAN

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have the following situation:

House 1: ISP provider A, modem/router from rovider A, some LAN/WLAN clients

House 2: ISP provider B, modem from provider B, network gear from unifi (USG-Pro-4, US-48-500W etc.), some LAN/WLAN clients, a NAS from Synology.

I can physically connect the two networks via a LAN-cable. My goal is to give a client from house 1 access to the NAS in house B. Otherwise the networks should remain untouched (still have their own ISP, router with active DHCP etc.)

What is the best way to achieve that?

My NAS has two NICs, so I could connect it directly to House 2. But is there another solution?

---

Solution 1:
I added a third router that connects the two networks like this:
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw4rB.jpg)

It all works fine now, but is there a way to do it without a third router? Maybe using the second LAN/WAN on the USG-PRO-4?

Comment: If both LANs are on differently numbered subnets (e.g. 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x), then this becomes a _very basic_ networking task: you just have two networks and a router in between...

Comment: at the moment, they both are 192.168.1.x, but I can make one to 192.168.2.x.
So I'll need a third router to do that?

Comment: Yes, you should change one of them. (Connecting LANs with different IP ranges is very easy, if they're identical it's quite troublesome.) After that, the USG-Pro-4 should be perfect for the task of routing between two networks. Unfortunately I don't know how its config screens work.

Comment: sounds promising, still I have no idea what to do and how to do it though.

Comment: are you just looking to make the two networks reachable from both client sides? or are you trying to combine both ISP connections?

Comment: just connect the two networks, so that they are reachable form both sides. Otherwise they should stay completely autonomous (keep their own ISP etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Create two vlans,

Vlan10 = 192.168.1.0 /24
Assuming router1 is 192.168.1.1

Vlan20 = 192.168.2.0 /24
Assuming router2 is 192.168.2.1

Assign the ports you want associated with each separated vlan. None will need to be tagged here.

Assign the two server nics a static IP,

Like:

Nic1 = 192.168.1.254 (plug into vlan10 assigned port)

Nic2 = 192.168.2.254 (plug into vlan20 assigned port)

Just use the switch as if it was two physical networks. Assign 1-24 to vlan10 & 25-48 to vlan20 if that makes it easier. Assuming your sfp's aren't counted as one of the 48.

Comment: that would work, but i'd rather not use the 2nd NIC of the NAS. At the moment, i use both NICs as link aggregation for more speed.

Comment: If you need to keep it aggregated, it sounds like you are ready for a 802.1q capable router. You can either go the way in the answer, or you can setup vlans, and have a trunk going back to the router so that both subnets can reach the aggregated Nas.

Comment: Let me know, I'll update the answer on how to do it if you want.

Comment: I updated my question. I have a solution with a third router in between the two networks. That works fine, the two networks stay as they are. But is there a way to do it without the third router?

Comment: Without a router in-between, you would need to separate it by vlan as mentioned in the answer.